# Selenium WebDriverWait does not throw timeout exception

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I am using selenium to scrape web. The web is similar to google map, I need to input a start location and end location and then get the results. The webpage loads slowly and sometimes stops responding. so I try use WebDriverWait to catch a timeout exception and restart the webpage.

However, in fact if the webpage stops responding, the webDriverWait does not throw timeout exception and the code just gets stuck forever.
For example, last time, my code stuck at invisibility_of_element_located and does not respond even the timeout is set to 10s.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@ng-show='route.isCalculating']")))
```

Comment: **invisibility_of_element_located**

An Expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM might be the condition is true and thats why its not throwing timeout exception.
Since i dont no anything about your code i only assume it might happen.

Answer (score 1):

You could try wrapping the wait in a try / except block to see if you can catch the `TimeOutException`:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    print("Attempting to locate element")
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@ng-show='route.isCalculating']")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("TimeoutException encountered")
print("Task complete")
```

Based on what prints out in the console, you probably determine whether or not the exception is hit at all.

If `TimeoutException` is not caught, you can just use `except:` and see if anything is being caught at all.